# Jupyterでのc++kernel(cling)の使用について

Tags: python, c++, c++11

macOS 10.12.4です。
anacondaはウェブページからdmgで落としてきたもので、conda update --all をしているのでanacondaそのもののバージョンはcustomとなっています。Jupyter notebookのバージョンは5.0.0です。

https://github.com/vgvassilev/cling/tree/master/tools/Jupyter
上のリンクの指示に従いclingをjupyterに導入しようとして、作業自体はエラーを吐くこともなく終了したのですが、いざカーネルをC++17にしてもDead Kernelとなり、最終的にRestartもできなくなります。当然全く使えません。

```
[IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | The 'stdin_port' trait of an IPKernelApp instance must be an int, but a value of 'c++17' <class 'str'> was specified.
```

というログが出ているので、これが原因だろうと思い、https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/options/kernel.html のIPKernelApp.stdin_portを確認したところ上記ログと符合することは確かに書いてあるのですが、具体的にどうすればいいかわかりません。

どなたかご教授いただけないでしょうか?